# python check if an object is in a list of objects

Tags: python

i'm trying to check if a certain object of mine is in a list of objects,

and i want to do it without going in nested loops.

i have for example an object of type X with fields of types W,E,R.

i also have a list L of objects of type X.

my question is - if i will ask, (myobj in L)

will it return True if there is an object of type X in  the list, OR will it

return True only if there is an object of type X in L, that have the same W,E,R

of myobj?

======================= edited: ======================================

first time i ran the above code (i.e. obj in L),

```
for log in logs[first_users[0]]:
    self.assertTrue(log in first_users[0].get_log())
```

for the above code i got an error because i had a log that wasn't in

first_users[0].get_log() (it was different by one object)

then i ran:

```
for log in first_users[0].get_log():
        self.assertTrue(log in logs[first_users[0]])
```

and i didn't get any errors - which is good.

i even tried to change a specific object in the logs:

```
for log in first_users[0].get_log():
    log.obj = None
    log.save()
    self.assertTrue(log in logs[first_users[0]])
```

and it still didn't through an error - which isn't good

Comment: So what have you tried then? If you want answers you'll need to ask a real question by showing your code, research, and efforts made to solve the problem on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Go through [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). It's the page on operator overloading in classes. Find the function that you need!

Edit: You need to implement `__eq__` to check if the members of two objects are equal.
Eg:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.val == other.val:
            return True
        return False

l = [Foo(i) for i in range(10)]
print(Foo(2) in l)
print(Foo(100) in l)
```

Output:

```
True
False
```

You can choose not to check all the members and compare only the ones that matter to you.

Comment: thank you! this one changed py2 -> py3, it's a hard one to search for :)